# Harddrive won't mount in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I've got an external hard drive, that doesn't seem to want to mount in Windows 7. The drive was working but unfortunately Windows froze (I even got a windows has stopped responding - do you want to restart dialog?). So I had to hit the reset button on my PC. The disk may have been being read at the time.

Unfortunately after coming back up the disk refuses to mount. I've tried:

- Swapping the USB Port
- Restarting the PC again properly
- Within disk management (it does appear in there)

  - Taking the disk offline/online
  - Mark Parition as Active / Change Drive Letters and Paths / Format all of which fail with either "Disk Management console view is not up-to-date. Refresh the view" which I've tried or "An unexpected error has occurred".
  - Deleting the volume and re-creating

So I'm left with a drive that I don't feel has fully died and could probably be recovered (gives the impression all the hardware is working). If my diagnosis is correct is there anything else I can do in Windows to try and get this things working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after plugging away at this for a while, and asking this question I found the answer almost immediately afterwards. Googling a bit more led me to this [article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/disk-management-console-view-is-not-up-to-date/42b1ebc3-edaf-4c3f-93cd-beda4bab2671?auth=1).

Essentially uninstalling the drivers, re-inserting the USB connector and allowing the drivers to re-install fixed the problem. For anyone not sure how to find the drivers, you can do so via Disk management:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The solution was to assign a new letter to the drive in disk management and voila, the drive became usable in Windows 7.